# Intellij cucumber plugin default step definition (Java)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber-java

I'm working with the IntelliJ Cucumber plugin for Java. The plugin is great, and I've gotten it to work with all my tests. My question relates to the automatic step definition creation feature that occurs when the user presses `Alt + Enter` on a undefined step and selects a file to place the newly created method.

Currently, the method is named the same as the step and is empty excepting for a `throw new PendingException()`.

Is there any way to change what the plugin places into the method on default? I'd like to change it to flag the step as a failing test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default step definition text [is hard-coded](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins/blob/master/cucumber-java/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/cucumber/java/steps/JavaSnippet.java).

Answer (score 0):

The Snippet is generated to give you an example of how you can implement the step definition. You have to implement it yourself as Cucumber does not know what you are trying to do.